# E0028 expression must have a constant value. I want to enter the n like a constant number. Thanks

Tags: c++

Hello I have tried to entering `n` division number by a number or a constant.
Here is the code:

```
}
int main()
{
//The main problem in below
int n_temp;
std::cout << "Please enter the division number";
std::cin >> n_temp;
const unsigned int n = n_temp;
int const iter_n = 10;
double const dx = L / (n - 1);
double T[n];
double P[n], Q[n];
double kP, kE, kW, ke, kw, Sp, Sc;
double a[n], b[n], c[n], d[n];
T[0] = 300; T[n - 1] = 1000;
for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) { T[i] = 500; }
std::cout << "T= ["; for (double T_i : T) { std::cout << T_i << ","; } std::cout << "]\n";
for (int iter = 0; iter < iter_n; iter++) {
a[0] = 1; b[0] = 0; c[0] = 0; d[0] = T[0];
a[n - 1] = 1; b[n - 1] = 0; c[n - 1] = 0; d[n - 1] = T[n - 1];
for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
float x = i * dx;
Sp = Spv(T[i], x);
Sc = Scv(T[i], x);
kP = kv(T[i], x);
kE = kv(T[i + 1], x + dx);
kW = kv(T[i - 1], x - dx);
ke = 2 * kP * kE / (kP + kE);
kw = 2 * kP * kW / (kP + kW);
b[i] = ke / dx;
c[i] = kw / dx;
a[i] = b[i] + c[i] + Sp * dx;
d[i] = Sc * dx;
}
P[0] = 0;
Q[0] = d[0];
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
P[i] = b[i] / (a[i] - c[i] * P[i - 1]);
Q[i] = (c[i] * Q[i - 1] + d[i]) / (a[i] - c[i] * P[i - 1]);
}
for (int i = n - 2; i > 0; i--) {
T[i] = P[i] * T[i + 1] + Q[i];
}
std::cout << "T =["; for (double T_i : T) { std::cout << T_i << ","; } std::cout << "]\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

Here is the revised version which is after reviewing comments. There are some errors that appear in the `T`. For example E2291,C3536, C2893, C2784, C2672,C2100 Thanks.

```
int main()
{
int n_temp;
std::cout << "Please enter the division number";
std::cin >> n_temp;
const unsigned int n = n_temp;
int const iter_n = 10;
double const dx = L / (n - 1);
double*T= new double[n];
double*P = new double[n];
double*Q= new double[n];
double kP, kE, kW, ke, kw, Sp, Sc;
double*a= new double[n];
double*b = new double[n];
double* c = new double[n];
double* d = new double[n];
T[0] = 300; T[n - 1] = 1000;
for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) { T[i] = 500; }
std::cout << "T= ["; for (double T_i : T) { std::cout << T_i << ","; } std::cout << "]\n";
for (int iter = 0; iter < iter_n; iter++) {
a[0] = 1; b[0] = 0; c[0] = 0; d[0] = T[0];
a[n - 1] = 1; b[n - 1] = 0; c[n - 1] = 0; d[n - 1] = T[n - 1];
for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
float x = i * dx;
Sp = Spv(T[i], x);
Sc = Scv(T[i], x);
kP = kv(T[i], x);
kE = kv(T[i + 1], x + dx);
kW = kv(T[i - 1], x - dx);

ke = 2 * kP * kE / (kP + kE);
kw = 2 * kP * kW / (kP + kW);

b[i] = ke / dx;
c[i] = kw / dx;
a[i] = b[i] + c[i] + Sp * dx;
d[i] = Sc * dx;
}
P[0] = 0;
Q[0] = d[0];

for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
P[i] = b[i] / (a[i] - c[i] * P[i - 1]);
Q[i] = (c[i] * Q[i - 1] + d[i]) / (a[i] - c[i] * P[i - 1]);
}
for (int i = n - 2; i > 0; i--) {
T[i] = P[i] * T[i + 1] + Q[i];
}
std::cout << "T =["; for (double T_i : T) { std::cout << T_i << ","; } std::cout << "]\n";
delete[]T;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could use `double *T = new double[n];` to create an array dynamically, and you need to release it at the end of your program by `delete[] T`. [This article](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/) might help.

Comment: `std::vector<double>` would work and you wouldn't have to do any manual memory management. Variable length arrays are not standard C++.

Comment: @Mivik Thank you so much for the information. I have revised my code as per your suggestion. If it possible Could u check again my problem. Thanks

Comment: @RetiredNinja Also Thank you for your comment. I have a question.  I have to add std::vector<double>  in below section?                                                                        int n_temp;
std::cout << "Please enter the division number";
std::cin >> n_temp;
const unsigned int n = n_temp;                                                                                                   I have revised that section. Am did correctly? int n_temp;
    std::vector<double>cout << "Please enter the division number";
    std::vector<double>cin >> n_temp;

Comment: One more reason to prefer `std::vector` over a raw pointer. Your range based for loops would just work. It isn't clear what you're asking in your comment. `L` is undefined in your examples and they don't have any includes so they can't simply be copy/paste/compiled.

Comment: To replace your VLA declarations with a vector you would convert `double T[n];` to `std::vector<double> T = std::vector<double>(n);` or `auto T = std::vector<double>(n);` to save some redundant typing.

Comment: The only thing you would need to change are the 7 array declarations T, P, Q, a, b, c, and d. Your example code is also missing declarations of `Spv`, `Scv`, and `kv`.

Comment: @RetiredNinja OMG. It works now. Thank you so much. You are the best!!!